# Addressing variable with string

Tags: javascript, html, dom, constants

I want to write **hello** on a paragraph based on the button user clicks on. I have tried the following but it didn't help. How do I do it?

```js
const para1 = document.getElementById('para1');
const para2 = document.getElementById('para2');

const options = document.getElementsByClassName('option');
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  let foo = options[i].classList[1];
  options[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    process(foo)
  })
}

function process(x) {
  let goo = `para${x}`; //This doesn't work
  goo.textContent = "hello";
  console.log(x);
  console.log(goo);
}
```

```css
#para1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#para2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="option 1">Write on para1</button>
<button class="option 2">Write on para2</button>
<p id="para1"></p>
<p id="para2"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating the line

```
let goo = `para${x}`; //This doesn't work
```

with

```
let goo = window['para'+x];
```

shall work

Accessing javascript variable as strings is done with bracket [] syntax:

```js
//global variables:
var foo = "hello";
var bar = "foo";
console.log(window[bar]); //prints "hello"

//for objects:
var someObject = {
  "foo": "hello"
};
var bar = "foo";
console.log(someObject[bar]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to set a property `textContent` on a string, not on the element. Instead of a string `x` in a method `process`, you need to pass found element.

```js
const para1 = document.getElementById('para1');
const para2 = document.getElementById('para2');

const options = document.getElementsByClassName('option');
for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
  let option = options[i];
  options[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
    process(option); // passing the element button.option
  })
}

function process(option) {
  const x = option.classList[1]; // get second class name
  const para = document.getElementById(`para${x}`); // find paragraph by id
  para.textContent = "hello"; // set text on paragraph
}
```

```css
#para1 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}

#para2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<button class="option 1">Write on para1</button>
<button class="option 2">Write on para2</button>
<p id="para1"></p>
<p id="para2"></p>
```

Comment: I meant to call variables from strings, not this.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to set the textContent of a string instead of a DOM node.

```js
function process(x) {
  let goo = document.getElementById(`para${x}`); //Try this instead
  goo.textContent = "hello";
  console.log(x);
  console.log(goo);
}
```

Comment: I meant calling variables from strings, not this.